# How to get text aligned to the top of a floated image

Tags: css, css-float

When I float images on my WordPress site, the text is not aligned vertically with the image, but appears a bit lower on the page. I suspect this is to do with line-height of the text, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's the example. Scroll to the bottom of the page under Recommended by:

http://www.myfiveacres.com/hidden-gems/saison-market-vineyard-duncan-bc-canada/

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Would you mind sharing the relevant code snippets along with the post.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should post your code, but one thing you could try is adding a negative top margin to your text.

`margin-top:-*px;`

And of course, replace the * with however many pixels are needed.